# How to read rrd files using rrdtool

Tags: python, rrdtool, rrd

I need to get specific data field from rrdtool. Here I have xml output of my rrdfile.

```
<ds>
    <name> gauge1 </name>
    <type> COUNTER </type>
    <minimal_heartbeat> 600 </minimal_heartbeat>
    <min> 0.0000000000e+00 </min>
    <max> 1.0000000000e+08 </max>

    <!-- PDP Status -->
    <last_ds> 10109068304313 </last_ds>
    <value> 1.2791603667e+05 </value>//need to read this value
    <unknown_sec> 0 </unknown_sec>
</ds>

<ds>
    <name> gauge2 </name>
    <type> COUNTER </type>
    <minimal_heartbeat> 600 </minimal_heartbeat>
    <min> 0.0000000000e+00 </min>
    <max> 1.0000000000e+08 </max>

    <!-- PDP Status -->
    <last_ds> 8604908605180 </last_ds>
    <value> 1.2595538667e+05 </value>//need to read this value
    <unknown_sec> 0 </unknown_sec>
</ds>
```

I am using following commands to read rrdfiles.

```
file_path=r'/data/rrd_new/XXX.rrd'
rrdfilename = file_path
rrd = rrdtool.lastupdate(rrdfilename)
time = rrd['date']
ds = rrd['ds']

print(time,ds)
```

But this provides output as below, which is the value of `<last_ds>`

```
2022-05-23 11:25:01 {'gauge1': 10109068304313.0, 'gauge2':  8604908605180}
```

But I need to get the value of  and outout should be as follows,

```
2022-05-23 11:25:01 {'gauge1': 127916.03667, 'gauge2':  125955.38667}
```

Can someone help me to read this?

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, the `lastupdate()` function returns the data from the *last update*, IE the update time, and the `last_ds`.  The `value` you see in the XML is really the workspace where the current pdp is being built, and does not have a specific function to retrieve it.

You can, of course, call the `info()` function, and then from the returned data extract `ds[gauge1].value` and similar.  This may be what you want.

Probably the better way would be to use `xport()` and extract the latest value in a 1cdp=1pdp RRA, if you have one in the RRD.  This will let you pull out the most recent value in the highest-granularity RRA.